# Is there any difference between https://example.com/path/to/url and https://example.com//path/to/url?

Tags: wordpress, caching, https, path, uri

I encountered an interesting issue where I replaced an image file in the WordPress file manager, but when I accessed the URL, the original file was still displayed. Despite my attempts to fix the problem, it persisted. Eventually, I discovered that adding a slash after the domain name resolved the issue.

Is there any difference between `https://example.com/path/to/url` and `https://example.com//path/to/url`?

I think this is due to the server's caching problem. Anyone can explain about this?

https://l2bc95.n3cdn1.secureserver.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/page-title-img.jpg
https://l2bc95.n3cdn1.secureserver.net//wp-content/uploads/2016/09/page-title-img.jpg

Comment: Please try to visit these two links above.

Comment: You will see 2 other images even though they are the same url except one slash(/).

Comment: Your browser can still read the URL but you might run in trouble with duplicate contend from search engines. Anything in your code seems to be off...

Comment: I'm no expert here but maybe that's just proper behavior. Is it required behavior that caching servers do lookups by a canonical URL? Canonicalizing can be expensive and what's the benefit? As for your caching issue, that can happen at different levels and probably requires more information to diagnose.